# In outlook add-ins make any API request like third party app authentication getting cors error?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

In outlook add-ins make any API request for authentication any third party API getting cors error  , why this problem occurs  ,

what is the reason for this issue , reason for this issue frond end side or API side

example :  if i make any request to microsoft API or salsforce authentication getting cors error ,

For any other request in microsoft office with access token , it is working  fine ,only getting this error any authentication request

Note : **This issue comes from local environment and add-in developed using javascript**

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue. Can you please elaborate on the error that you receive when you try to authenticate?

Note: Have you added all domains you are calling in AppDomain [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomain] element in the manifest.

Comment: Yes I have added all the domains in manifest file ,  and if i make authentication request to salesforce "/services/oauth2/authorize" and microsoft graph  API  "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" from client i am getting the cors error  , suppose i have create simple node js server , and make a request from node js error not getting , only getting client side , In client side i am using any proxy instead of auth url , it is working but this is not a correct solution , i want correct solution

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. 

1. May I know the version of Exchange you are using?
2. Has the auth stopped working for an existing add-in or any new add-in?
3. Was it successful on any other platforms except OWA?
4. Is the behavior consistent across the browsers?


Note: 
Calling REST APIs from add-ins are only supported in Exchange Online or in hybrid environments.

We don't support client-side requests in on-premises Exchange deployments. For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api#call-the-api